# Managing loosely coupled assembly references incurred through usage of the 'Designer' attribute

Tags: c#, components, designer, windows-forms-designer, design-time

We build a lot of components, WinForms, Workflow activities etc, and something that we use a lot is the 'Designer' attribute.
The general practice during initial development is, the Designer attribute is used with the `[Designer(typeof(DesignerType))]` style to get things working - then later, this is converted to `[Designer("AssemblyQualifiedTypeName")]`, which allows the designer DLL to be removed from the component's reference list - this removes the need for the component consumer to have to deploy the designer DLL with their product.
This practice of splitting the design-time, and run-time code into two seperate DLLs is common practice, and one that I am a proponent of.

A negative side effect, is the 'assembly qualified type name' will include the assembly version of the designer dll, so when the version is incremented, one must perform a 'search and replace' across the product to ensure they have updated all the 'loose references' to this designer.

Finally, my question:
Can anyone reccomend a best practice that doesnt rely on 'search and replace', which can manage all these references, to ensure they are always up to date?
We often get a lazy developer forgetting to update the reference string, resulting in a new version of the component linking to the previous version of the designer DLL - which of course doesnt get deployed, so design-time support is lost.
Perhaps some form of pragmas, macros, build script, magic attributes, I dont know, but there must be a better way of doing this.

Anyone? (thanks)

Comment: Why are you incrementing the [AssemblyVersion] of the designer?  It doesn't make any sense, you don't deploy them.

Comment: Hi Hans, we are building developer components and selling it as an SDK, so we give the component DLL, and the designer DLL to our customers, and they use the components to build products, they (in turn) deploy just the component with their product.
Because they may have two or more versions of the SDK installed, the component needs to load the correct version of the designer, as such, it necessary for the designer DLL to be versioned aswell.

Answer (score 1):

Why not create a single designer that uses something like the Managed Addin Framework or Activator.CreateInstance internally to pick and show a designer? With this technique, the Designer attribute would never have to change...

Comment: Hi Alex - how we one to that? The 'DesignerAttribute' is read by the Visual Studio root-designer (i.e. the Forms designer, or the WF Activity Designer). As such, the DesignerAttribute is a necessary evil, and there is no way (from my understanding) to get in-between Visual Studio, and the component.

Comment: When VS or the WF designer sees that you've applied the attribute to a class, it will actually create an instance of that class and use it. You know this because the custom designers you've written work as expected. But instead of showing a UI, you can write code that dynamically creates an instance of a class based on some configuration setting perhaps. Instead of MAF or Activator.CreateInstance, you might also use something like Spring.NET or Unity.

Comment: Im sorry Alex, I understand what you are describing, but dont see how to achieve this.
Visual Studio creates an instance of a Designer (and it must be a designer) that is 'referenced' by the DesignerAttribute, and I have no control over what it does with it... which is typically to  display it in the design window.
Can you explain with pseudo-code what you mean?

Answer (score 0):

Do it like Microsoft does. Take a look at AssemblyRef class (System.Windows.Forms.dll) in Reflector.